# Set focus in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

Fairly simple question I have. I'm trying to set focus to a specific EditText on a fragment in a ViewPager. I have tried both methods I know of.

```
<EditText
.....
..... >
<requestFocus />
</EditText
```

And I also tried:

```
EditText.requestFocus();
```

Neither method worked for me. Is this because I'm trying to do so in a fragment? Am I doing it wrong? Is there a better method?

I apologize in advance if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```